# onclick event does not work for editbox in firewatir

Tags: watir, firewatir

I am facing problem for onclick event fire event method it is not working in firefox(3.5.6) while fine in IE

when i run the script in Firefox it does not perform the onlcick event opeartion, just execute the step without giving any error
While same code when i run on IE it is working fine.Is it firewatir bug? onclick event does not work for editbox in firewatir

```
$ie.form(:id ,"mainForm").text_field(:id, "ItemTagSearchWidgetGameDate").fire_event("onclick")
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="click here to pick a game date" class="gameDate" onclick="bam.dateSelector.prepareAndShow(this)" style="width: 235px;" id="ItemTagSearchWidgetGameDate">
```

I am using firewatir (1.6.5)

Is this bug with firewatir ?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

1) try just firing .click at it

```
browser.text_field(:id, "ItemTagSearchWidgetGameDate").click
```

I would generally only try the fire_event method where using simple .click fails, or a different more specific event is being looked for.

Also you will note I dropped the .form stuff, because the text input field has a unique ID, there is no need to specify an outer container.  You only need to do that sort of thing with elements which lack an easy means of being uniquely identified and you are forced to find them via their position inside some container element that is easier to identify.

2) Try using Watir-Webdriver instead of Firewatir.  You get cross browser capability, and it supports newer versions of firefox, where Firewatir cannot due to the lack of any JSSH support in any of the more recent versions (7, 6, 5, etc)